# SQL Server Reporting Services in TFS

Tags: reporting-services, tfs

I receive the following error message when opening a TFS report:

> **An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>       Query execution failed for dataset 'dsIteration'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
>           For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors**

Comment: Need more info. TFS Version? Have you got TFS 2010 service pack 1 installed? Assuming this is TFS 2010, has the the analysis database has completed at least one rebuild?

Comment: TFS Version is 2010. yes

Comment: Is this one of the out of the box TFS reports? Which one? Is the report correctly configured to use the right datasource? Is the datasource properly configured to connect to the correct database?

Comment: No. please, help me to configure to use the datasource or connect to database.

Answer (score 1):

This Error will pop up if the Dataset has the insufficient execute permission. Check that database your are using and give the execute permission if not.

Open Sql Server Mgmt Studio(SSMS) and log in through the user you are trying to access the report. Run the SQL Query in SSMS and make sure there is no error while running the script.

Run the report and For more help check in the log file of report server. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles this location may change according to your installation. here you can get clear idea of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the TFS server and rebuilding the reporting databases fixed this for me.